# Why is my Twitter feed suddenly flooded with posts?

Tags: twitter, iphone

I have a Twitter account, and I follow a couple of my friends. When I usually check my Twitter feed, I can see what my friends have posted and reply to it or whatever.

But lately, I've noticed that my Twitter feed is suddenly getting *flooded* with posts. From people I don't follow or am even interested in following. I'm getting tweets from MTV, ESPN, SportsCenter, Billboard, Imagine Dragons, Justin Bieber, Wiz Khalifa, Perez Hilton, BuzzFeed, the New York Times, and the list just goes on and on. I'm even getting posts from people with 15 followers. Every time I refresh the page, there's about a dozen more new tweets in my Twitter feed.

This has made Twitter completely and utterly unusable for me.

What's going on, and how do I stop it?

EDIT: Strangely, this only happens on the Twitter app on my iPhone; nothing of this sort happens on my computer.

Answer (score 1):

Check who you are following.   It's possible that someone has hacked in to your account, not changed the password, but signed you up to follow all sort.    If they have, change your password ASAP, and then start unfollowing.

Comment: I checked and I'm still following the same group of people as usual. What's strange is that this only happens on my iPhone app; for the Twitter website on my computer, it's showing only tweets from my friends.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a 3rd party app, rather than an official app released by Twitter (assuming there is such a thing - I'm not in iAnything user so cannot check), then it's possible that the 3rd party is injecting their own "sponsored" tweets into your feed.

Check to see if there's an official app (or even a different 3rd party one) and start using that.